# enqueue script with php decisions

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

In wordpress, the recommended option to use java script is with `wp_enqueue_script()`, but what if I want to put some php in that script? for example, look at this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        <?php if ( !is_front_page() ){ ?>
            $('.primary-menu').hide('slow', 'swing'); 
            $('.site-logo').css('height', '60px').css('padding-bottom', '0');
            $('#masthead').css('height', '5px'); 
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ( !mida_is_english() ) : ?>
            $('.site-header').addClass('shrink');
            $("#masthead.site-header.shrink")
            .find('.site-logo img')
            .attr('src', '<?php echo $upload_dir['baseurl']?>/2015/12/extra-cropped-logo.jpg'); 
        <?php else : ?>
            $('.site-header').addClass('shrink');
            $("#masthead.site-header.shrink")
            .find('.site-logo img')
            .attr('src', '<?php echo $upload_dir['baseurl']?>/2015/10/mida-eng-logo.png'); 
        <?php endif; ?>             
    }
    else{ //some more code....
```

How can I enqueue this code? I can just put it in php file and use `wp_enqueue_script()` to enqueue that file?

Hope my question make sense..

Answer (score 0):

If you're not willing to add that code to the *footer.php* file of your site, you can use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass data to your JavaScript

```
// Localize the script with new data
$data = array(
    'is_front_page' => is_front_page(),
    'is_english' => mida_is_english()
);
wp_localize_script( 'your-registered-script-handle', 'page_info', $data );
```

Note that you may need to hook this later than the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook, in order for it to work. You can then use it in your JS via:

```
// This is in a JavaScript file
if ( !page_info.is_front_page ) {
    // Do stuff
}
if ( !page_info.is_english ) {
    // Do some other stuff
}
```

All of that said, I recommend just injecting the code you mentioned into `wp_footer`, instead of messing with localization...

Comment: you mean something like this: `add_action ('wp_footer', 'function_name', 1);`? Is this a good practice?